# Adding value of two table into new table aspnet C# webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two table are as follows.

Table name: `Action01`

```
ID    Label01
1     Orange
2     Mango
3     Lemon
```

Table name: `Action02`

```
ID       Label02
1        05 qty
2        10 Qty
3        06 Qty
```

These two table get the values on data entering on server

I want to add the values into new table name: PurchaseList

Table name: `PurchaseList`

```
ID    Purchasing
1     Orange, 05 qty 
2     Mango, 10 qty
3     Lemon, 06 qty
```

Can anybody tell me how to add the above two columns (Label 01 and Label 02) into new table column (purchasing) .

Purpose is to show purchasing column value into the textbody of front page and then later it will be use in my SQL reporting.

Regards
Tahir

Comment: Do you need to combine them into a single column or can your PurchaseList Table have 3 columns?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to persist this column. This is redundant data. You could create a View and concatenate the two columns on the fly.

Comment: Dear PseudoNym01, i want to combine them into a single column. You may be give me idea about getting purchase list having 3 coloumn. Any suggestion please :)

Comment: Dear CodeWorx, Can you give me some hints about what you are saying. Actually, my objective to store combine data into table which later be used in my sql reporting.